How can we sketch a 3D histogram and 2D hinton diagrams with Latex?
I am trying to draw a 3D histogram and a 2D Hinton diagram same as these images:


Here is my code:
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
colorbar,
colormap/viridis,
title={$\rho_{in}$ ($N$ = 3, $n$ = 1, $m$ = 0) },
grid=major,
view={120}{40},
width=220pt,
height=220pt,
%
xlabel={Quantum State},
xlabel style={sloped like x axis},
tick label style={font=\small},
ylabel={Quantum State},
ylabel style={sloped like y axis},
zlabel={Absolute value},
zmin=0, zmax=1, 
%
xtick={8,7,...,0},
ytick={0,1,...,8}, 
xticklabels={$|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$, $|3\rangle$, $|4\rangle$, $|5\rangle$, $|6\rangle$, $|7\rangle$, $|8\rangle$},
yticklabels={$|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, $|2\rangle$, $|3\rangle$,     $|4\rangle$,     $|5\rangle$, $|6\rangle$, $|7\rangle$, $|8\rangle$},
%
zmin=0,
zmax=1, 
enlargelimits=false,
tick align=outside,
xtick distance=1, ytick distance=1,
mesh/ordering=y varies, 
mesh/cols=9, % Number of columns in the mesh
mesh/rows=9, % Number of rows in the mesh
point meta min=0, 
point meta max=1,
unbounded coords = jump,
]
\addplot3+ [%
surf,mark=none,
faceted color=black,
mesh/rows=9, 
] table [] {rho_in.dat};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Here is the data for rho_in.dat:
0 0 0.0
0 1 0.0
0 2 0.0
0 3 0.0
0 4 0.0
0 5 0.0
0 6 0.0
0 7 0.0
0 8 0.0
1 0 0.0
1 1 0.0
1 2 0.0
1 3 0.0
1 4 0.0
1 5 0.0
1 6 0.0
1 7 0.0
1 8 0.0
2 0 0.0
2 1 0.0
2 2 0.0
2 3 0.0
2 4 0.0
2 5 0.0
2 6 0.0
2 7 0.0
2 8 0.0
3 0 0.0
3 1 0.0
3 2 0.0
3 3 1.0
3 4 0.0
3 5 0.0
3 6 0.0
3 7 0.0
3 8 0.0
4 0 0.0
4 1 0.0
4 2 0.0
4 3 0.0
4 4 0.0
4 5 0.0
4 6 0.0
4 7 0.0
4 8 0.0
5 0 0.0
5 1 0.0
5 2 0.0
5 3 0.0
5 4 0.0
5 5 0.0
5 6 0.0
5 7 0.0
5 8 0.0
6 0 0.0
6 1 0.0
6 2 0.0
6 3 0.0
6 4 0.0
6 5 0.0
6 6 0.0
6 7 0.0
6 8 0.0
7 0 0.0
7 1 0.0
7 2 0.0
7 3 0.0
7 4 0.0
7 5 0.0
7 6 0.0
7 7 0.0
7 8 0.0
8 0 0.0
8 1 0.0
8 2 0.0
8 3 0.0
8 4 0.0
8 5 0.0
8 6 0.0
8 7 0.0
8 8 0.0

I have an issue with it. Could you please give me your comments on solving this issue and also having 2D Hinton diagrams with Latex for the data?
